# [SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated thrown

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I'm getting a very vague error.  I have the following code:

```
var skey = ev.EntityKey;
var id = skey.EntityKeyValues[0];
int eventid = (int)id.Value;
```

The second line var id=skey.EntityKeyValues[0] throws the following exception:

[SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.]

Trouble is, EntityKeyValues[0] is code to get the primary key value of the newly inserted record and pass it to a method.

It is a string but I don't see why it should be particuarly large.

Comment: This exception can never be thrown by a C# statement. It is thrown when you try to save a value in a database field that is too small for it. So investigate the value and the width of the target field.